# Displaying a Google API Map on Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This morning I had a working map and was trying to get some dropdown objects, in the process of that I've now screwed it up and don't have a working map.

I have a rawimage object with the Google API script inside and I've assigned the rawimage object to the rawimage variable. I'm getting a red question mark.

At one point it worked like literally until I stopped the app and played it again, hadn't touched any code or anything. It worked, then it didn't. I think that was to do with the API key though as I tried to change it beforehand.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GoogleAPI : MonoBehaviour
{

    public string url; 

    public RawImage map;

    public float lon;
    public float lat;

   public int zoom;
   public int mapHeight;
   public int mapWidth;
   public int scale;

   LocationInfo li;

   public enum mapType { roadMap, satelite, hybrid, terrain };
   public mapType mapSelected;

   private IEnumerator mapCoroutine;

   IEnumerator GoogleMaps(float lat, float lon)
   {


    url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + lat + 
          "," + lon + "&zoom=" + zoom + "&size=" + mapHeight + "x" + 
           mapWidth + "&Scale=" + scale+ "&maptype=" + mapSelected +
           "&key=AIzaSyDh1_nS-l7nWOFWvt0Gg9-9dY_11qWzK_Q";


    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www; 
    map.texture = www.texture;


}



void Start()
{
    map = this.gameObject.GetComponent<RawImage>();
    StartCoroutine(GoogleMaps(lat, lon));
    lat = 53.26532f;
    lon = -4.42914f;
    Debug.Log("new maps");
}

}
```

My question is, Can you see where I've gone wrong? I've seen a few tutorials, there isn't many. They all vary slightly, I've tried other things and still no joy.

The console shows no errors or information.

Thanks.

Comment: You are not seeing "new maps" in the console? Also, you're building the url with lat, long, zoom, height, width and scale set to 0. As a general hint, try adding some logging inside your coroutine to see if you're getting in there at all and where things might be getting hung up.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry it is showing " new maps". I tried putting the WWW www = new WWW(url); and the two line underneath into a try, catch with debug log but it says the yield can't be in a try. Where else would you have a debug log in that code?

Comment: Put one in right before `WWW www = new WWW(url)` and log the URL. You'll be able to take that and paste it into a browser to see what response you get from Google.

Comment: Oh thats cool! can see the api key has expired. I've generated at new key which still says expired!? this time getting g.co/staticmaperror/signature as opposed to a red question mark.

Comment: Just pasted the same url in to Google, now its just showing a picture of the grey map with error rather than any written information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!

The error was with Google API key. They have a limit of how many times per day the map can be generated. I put some code in the Update() with then generate a new map over 1000s times and used up all my go's.

Signed up for a free trial and added billing to the project on Googles API page and now it works.

Lol. Been at this all day.